# What are identifiers in java exactly?

Tags: java, parsing, identifier

I don't understand the full definition of a java identifier. For example in:

```
String st = "hello";
if(st.equals("hello") return st;
```

Would equals count as an identifier?
I need to create a program in which identifiers are detected in source code and stored if they are. But if the java library methods don't count as identifiers, then there's no way I could store only the programmed named variables, methods, and classes.

Comment: Yes, `equals` is an identifier.  I recommend reading [sections 3.8 and 3.9 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html)

Comment: It looks like the code insertion program for this forum doesn't color code the identifiers correct? Also what about special data structures like ArrayList? Are they identifiers?

Comment: What about a variable's defined value like in: int i = 1; is 1 an identifier?

Comment: The answer to whether `1` is an identifier is on the first line of the section that I recommended you to read.

Comment: Also, to write this program correctly, you need to replace Unicode escape sequences first, then strip out comments, before you search for identifiers.    The details are in the JLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick [Google search](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/08.html):

> Identifiers are the names of variables, methods, classes, packages and interfaces. Unlike literals they are not the things themselves, just ways of referring to them. In the HelloWorld program, HelloWorld, String, args, main and println are identifiers.

So in your case: `String`, `st`, and `equals` are all identifiers as they are the names of classes, variables, and methods respectively.

Comment: So far, my parser would only take in individual words minus the punctuation for each call of .next(). How would I be able to tell my program that the literals of variables are not identifiers?

Comment: That sounds like an entirely different question and one that depends on your source code. I would suggest posting a different, more specific question with your attempts at solving the problem.

Comment: Well, section 3.10 of the JLS (I won't give you the link again) tells you how to identify literals.

Answer (score 0):

An identifier is a name given to a variable, method, class, interface, or other program element. Identifiers are used to uniquely identify these program elements within your code.

`st`, `equals`, and `return` are identifiers.

`st`: This is a variable identifier of type String.

`equals`: This is a method identifier (a member function of the String class) used to compare strings.

`return`: This is a keyword used to return a value from a method.
Java library methods, such as equals in your example, are indeed considered identifiers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just for clarity: keywords themselves are not identifiers. "*An identifier cannot have the same spelling as a keyword*"—[spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)