# Java program images not showing up

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a *whack-a-mole* type of game in Java but when I run my program the images do not show up.

Here is my code so far and I will add the images as well. I am also fairly new to coding so this might be an easy fix.

[kuronomi.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43340.gif)

[kitty.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmPys.gif)

[This is what I see when I run my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHB5f.png)

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class hellokitty {
    int screenWidth = 700;
    int screenHeight = 800;
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Catch Hello Kitty!");
    JLabel textL = new JLabel();
    JPanel textP = new JPanel();
    JPanel boardP = new JPanel();
    
    JButton[] board = new JButton[9];
    ImageIcon kittyIcon;
    ImageIcon kuroIcon;
    
    JButton currentKittyTile;
    JButton currentKurTile;
    
    Random r = new Random();
    Timer setKittyTimer;
    Timer setKuroTimer;

    hellokitty(){
        //frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    
        textL.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 70));
        textL.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        textL.setText("Score: 0");
        textL.setOpaque(true);
    
        textP.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        textP.add(textL);
        frame.add(textP, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    
        boardP.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        boardP.setBackground(Color.pink);
        frame.add(boardP);
    
        Image KittyImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("./kitty.gif")).getImage();
        kittyIcon = new ImageIcon(KittyImg.getScaledInstance(150, 150, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    
        Image KuronomiImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("./kuronomi.gif")).getImage();
        kuroIcon = new ImageIcon(KuronomiImg.getScaledInstance(150, 150, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i ++){
            JButton tile = new JButton();
            board[i] = tile;
            boardP.add(tile);
           // tile.setIcon(kuroIcon);
            tile.setFocusable(false);
        }

        setKittyTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (currentKittyTile != null) {
                currentKittyTile.setIcon(null);
                currentKittyTile = null;
            }
    
            int num = r.nextInt(9); 
            JButton tile = board[num];
    
            currentKittyTile = tile;
            currentKittyTile.setIcon(kittyIcon);
            }
        });
    
        setKuroTimer = new Timer(1500, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if (currentKurTile != null){
                    currentKurTile.setIcon(null);
                    currentKurTile = null;
                }
    
                int num = r.nextInt(9);
                JButton tile = board[num];
    
                currentKurTile = tile;
                currentKurTile.setIcon(kuroIcon);
            }
        });
    
        setKittyTimer.start();
        setKuroTimer.start();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `./kitty.gif` is weird; try `kitty.gif`. `getClass()` is dangerous; use `hellokitty.class.getResource("kitty.gif")`. That will look in the same place `hellokitty.class` (the file) exists. If it's in a jar file, it looks not just in that jar file, but in the same path. So, run `jar tvf myjar.jar` and confirm.

Comment: Use ImageIO to read image files. You will get an Exception message if the image is not found. See: [Loading Images Using getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource)

Comment: BTW it probably will work if using `Image.SCALE_FAST` instead of `SCALE_SMOOTH`, no idea why -- but that *method* of loading images (using `ImageIcon`) is very old and error prone, from the time when Applets were actual, please use `ImageIO` instead, as already commented and answered

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the easiest way to use [`getResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) is to put the resource in the same folder as the associated *.class* file. In your case that would mean putting files *kitty.gif* and *kuronomi.gif* in the same folder as file *hellokitty.class*. Then the URL of the resource can be obtained by calling:

```java
getClass().getResource("kitty.gif");
```

But even after you successfully obtain the resource, scaling the image as you do in your code will not work<sup>1</sup>. I am referring to these lines of your code:

```java
Image KittyImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("kitty.gif")).getImage();
kittyIcon = new ImageIcon(KittyImg.getScaledInstance(150, 150, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
```

Instead I used `BufferedImage`. Refer to [Why getScaledInstance() does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313911/why-getscaledinstance-does-not-work)

Here is my rewrite of your code – including a `main` method that uses a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). Also I changed some of the [identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311723/what-are-identifiers-in-java-exactly) so that they adhere to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class HelloKitty {
    int screenWidth = 700;
    int screenHeight = 800;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Catch Hello Kitty!");
    JLabel textL = new JLabel();
    JPanel textP = new JPanel();
    JPanel boardP = new JPanel();

    JButton[] board = new JButton[9];
    ImageIcon kittyIcon;
    ImageIcon kuroIcon;

    JButton currentKittyTile;
    JButton currentKurTile;

    Random r = new Random();
    Timer setKittyTimer;
    Timer setKuroTimer;

    HelloKitty() {
        // frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        textL.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 70));
        textL.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        textL.setText("Score: 0");
        textL.setOpaque(true);

        textP.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        textP.add(textL);
        frame.add(textP, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        boardP.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        boardP.setBackground(Color.pink);
        frame.add(boardP);

        URL url = getClass().getResource("kitty.gif");
        URL url2 = getClass().getResource("kuronomi.gif");
        try {
            Image img = ImageIO.read(url);
            Image kittyImg = img.getScaledInstance(150, 150, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            kittyIcon = new ImageIcon(kittyImg);
            Image img2 = ImageIO.read(url2);
            Image kuronomiImg = img2.getScaledInstance(150, 150, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            kuroIcon = new ImageIcon(kuronomiImg);
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                JButton tile = new JButton();
                board[i] = tile;
                boardP.add(tile);
                tile.setFocusable(false);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            throw new RuntimeException(xIo);
        }

        setKittyTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (currentKittyTile != null) {
                    currentKittyTile.setIcon(null);
                    currentKittyTile = null;
                }

                int num = r.nextInt(9);
                JButton tile = board[num];

                currentKittyTile = tile;
                currentKittyTile.setIcon(kittyIcon);
            }
        });

        setKuroTimer = new Timer(1500, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (currentKurTile != null) {
                    currentKurTile.setIcon(null);
                    currentKurTile = null;
                }

                int num = r.nextInt(9);
                JButton tile = board[num];

                currentKurTile = tile;
                currentKurTile.setIcon(kuroIcon);
            }
        });

        setKittyTimer.start();
        setKuroTimer.start();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new HelloKitty());
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture of the running app. Of-course the tiles that contain images change all the time due to your [timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/misc/timer.html).

[image: screen capture]

Now I guess you need to write [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/events/actionlistener.html)s to update the score whenever the user successfully "whacks a mole".

<sup>1</sup>I could not discover why.